# Delta Method generalized to two sequences of variables

Tags: probability-theory

This problem is a generalization of the delta method for two sequences of random variables.

Suppose we have $\{X_n\},\{Y_n\}$ two sequences of $k\times 1$ vector valued random variables, and a function $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^s$. Assume

$A1: X_n - Y_n \xrightarrow{p} 0$

$A2: a_n[X_n - Y_n] = Op(1)$

$A3:$ For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a set $B$ on which $f$ is uniformly differentiable and satisfying $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}  P(Y_n \notin B)  < \epsilon$.

Then, prove that we have

$a_n(f(X_n) -f(Y_n)) =  a_n\nabla f(Y_n^*)^T (X_n - Y_n) + op(1)$

where $Y_n^* = Y_n$ if $f$ is differentiable at $Y_n$ and $Y_n^*$ is an arbritrary value in $B$ otherwise.

Note: A3 is automatically satisfied if $Y_n = \theta$ and $f$ is differentiable at $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

$A_n = a_n[f(X_n) -f(Y_n) - \nabla f(Y_n)[X_n - Y_n]] $

We wish to prove that for any $\delta > 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $N$ such that $n > N$ implies

$P(|A_n| > \delta) < \epsilon$.

We can find a $B$ that satisfies A3 and a $N_y$ such that for $n > N_y$

$P( Y_n \notin B) < \epsilon/2$

For $Y_n \in B$, we can write

$\begin{align}
A_n &=  r_{Y_n}(X_n - Y_n)\times a_n(X_n - Y_n) 
\end{align}$

where $r_{y}(h) = [f(y+h)-f(y)]/h  -  \nabla f(y)$.

Because we have uniform differentiability over $B$

$\sup_{y \in B} |r_y(h)| = o(1)$ as $h \to 0$

this implies, with A2, that

$a_n(X_n - Y_n) \sup_{y \in B} |r_y(X_n - Y_n)| = Op(1)op(1) = op(1)$

hence we can find a $N_b$ such that $n > N_b$ implies

$P( a_n(X_n - Y_n) \sup_{y \in B} |r_y(X_n - Y_n)| > \delta ) < \epsilon/2$

Therefore, for $n > N, N = max(N_y, N_b)$, we have

$P( |A_n| > \delta) \le P(a_n(X_n - Y_n) \sup_{y \in B} |r_y(X_n - Y_n)| > \delta) + P(Y_n \notin B) < \epsilon$

which proves the statement.